# Windows11, WSL2: Unable to uninstall ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My ubuntu installation over WSL2 is a mess and I wish to start over. Per online instructions I uninstalled all 'Ubuntu' apps, and installed the latest one (22):
[image]

But in Terminal, previous Ubuntu installations still appear (with all their disk contents):
[image]

How do I actually uninstall them?

Answer (score 0):

To whomever it may concern, I was able to manually uninstall the rogue distros by `wsl --unregister <DistroName>`